# pdf estimation with scipy.stats

Tags: python, statistics, scipy

Say I compute the density of Beta(4,8):

```
from scipy.stats import beta
rv = beta(4, 8)
x = np.linspace(start=0, stop=1, num=200)
my_pdf = rv.pdf(x)
```

Why does the integral of the pdf not equal one?

```
> my_pdf.sum()
199.00000139548044
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The integral over the pdf is one.  You can see this by using numerical integration from scipy

```
>>> from scipy.integrate import quad
>>> quad(rv.pdf, 0, 1)
(0.9999999999999999, 1.1102230246251564e-14)
```

or by writing your own ad-hoc integration (with a trapezoidal rule in this example)

```
>>> x = numpy.linspace(start=0, stop=1, num=201)
>>> (0.5 * rv.pdf(x[0]) + rv.pdf(x[1:-1]).sum() + 0.5 * rv.pdf(x[-1])) / 200.0
1.0000000068732813
```

Comment: Thanks Sven. With this in mind, say I have the pdf stored in `my_pdf` and I want to compute the variance, do I still need to use `quad` to compute the integral:  `Var(x) = E(x-E(x))`? Or is there an easy way with `scipy.stats`?

Comment: You can do things like `mu=scipy.sum( x*my_pdf)/scipy.sum(my_pdf)` and `scipy.sum(my_pdf*(x-mu)**2)/(scipy.sum(my_pdf))` -- you are just dealing with a distribution that is not normalized.  Note: you are still subject to discretization errors.

Comment: Even better: you can use the `weight` argument in `scipy.average` so that the mean is `mu=scipy.average(x, weights=my_pdf)` and variance is `sigma_squared=scipy.average( (x-mu)**2 , weights=my_pdf)`

Answer (score 1):

`rv.pdf` returns the value of the pdf at each value of `x`. It doesn't sum to one because your aren't actually computing an integral. If you want to do that, you need to divide your sum by the number of intervals, which is `len(x) - 1`, which is 199. That would then give you a result very close to 1.

Comment: Why dividing by `len(x) - 1`?  I can't see any reason for applying that rule.

Comment: I am confused. If I collect a fine sample of the pdf, and I sum over this sample, shouldn't that be equivalent to integrating the pdf? Why do I have to divide by the length of x?

Comment: It's called the [Trapezoidal Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapezoidal_rule).

Comment: @user815423426 No. Suppose you collect a bunch of uniformly spaced samples over the interval and sum them to get a result. If you then do the same thing with double the number of samples, you'll get a sum that is also roughly double again. When you integrate, you have to consider the sample *interval* as well, not just the number of samples.

Comment: Thanks bogatron. That explanation was very helpful.

Comment: Just to clarify, Sven's answer is the correct implementation of the Trapezoid Rule. Simply dividing the sum by `len(x) - 1` doesn't account for the two end points having half the weight of the other points. For estimating your pdf integral, the difference is minor because those points are in the tails of the distribution. By just dividing the sum by 199, I get an estimated integral of 1.0000000070124644. But the main point with regard to your question is still that you have to account for the sample interval.